# Is the AJAX from image fields and multi-line fields breaking my JavaScript?

Tags: 8, javascript, ajax, tooltips

We have added tooltips to our node form using this method: https://inclusive-components.design/tooltips-toggletips/

It includes a JavaScript/jQuery snippet that works perfectly *except*...

- If the tooltip is inside an image file upload, it works, but if you upload an image and that field updates, then the tooltip no longer works.
- If the tooltip is inside a multi-line field, it works, but if you add a new item, the tooltip no longer works.

The other tooltips keep working. It's as if those tooltips were removed from the `document.querySelectorAll`. Would this have something to do with Drupal 8's AJAX updating those fields?

Here is the JS:

```
(function ($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("dom is ready");
    // Get all the toggletip buttons
    var toggletips = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggletip-content]');

    // Iterate over them
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(toggletips, function (toggletip) {
      // Get the message from the data-content element
      var message = toggletip.getAttribute('data-toggletip-content');

      // Get the live region element
      var liveRegion = toggletip.nextElementSibling;

      // Toggle the message
      toggletip.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log('clicky');
        liveRegion.innerHTML = '';
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          liveRegion.innerHTML = '<span class="alert alert-info isu-alert_sm isu-tooltip-bubble">'+ message +'</span>';
        }, 100);
      });

    // Close on outside click
    document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      if (toggletip !== e.target) {
        liveRegion.innerHTML = '';
      }
    });

    // Remove toggletip on ESC
    toggletip.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      if ((e.keyCode || e.which) === 27)
        liveRegion.innerHTML = '';
      });
      // Remove on blur
      toggletip.addEventListener('blur', function (e) {
        liveRegion.innerHTML = '';
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Note: I know absolutely nothing about AJAX other than it seems to be what's updating the fields's HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would this have something to do with Drupal 8's AJAX updating those
>   fields?

Yes, you need to add

#### Drupal.behaviors

In order for your Drupal JS code to be able to run after AJAX.

> using the functionality of `Drupal.behaviors` and `once()`. If used
>   properly this will ensure that your code runs both on normal page
>   loads **and when data is loaded by AJAX** (or BigPipe!)
>
> Any object defined as a property of `Drupal.behaviors` will get its
>   `attach()` method called when the DOM has loaded both initially **and
>   after any AJAX calls**.

I suggest you read the [Javascript API Overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview).

---

Alternatively, If you don't want to use `Drupal.behaviors`, I believe if you change all the `.addEventListener` to `.on` that will also do.

Comment: Thank you so much, @no-sssweat! This worked perfectly.